Swap 2 lines in text file with assembler
could someone provide an example how to swap 2 lines in txt document using assembly? I would be using it as an example, because right now i'm able to copy contents from one txt file to another, but can't figure it out how to swap line 2 and 3 for example, but leave everything else the same in a file
I tried doing it like this, but my program just crashes (this is just a part of code):
copy_and_swap:
    call ReadLine
    jc eof

    mov ax, currentLine
    cmp ax, line1
    je swap_with_line2
    cmp ax, line2
    je swap_with_line1

    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine
    jmp near copy_and_swap

swap_with_line2:
    lea di, tempBuf
    lea si, buf
    mov cx, 128
    rep movsb
    call ReadLine
    call WriteLine
    ; Įrašyti išsaugotą eilutę
    lea si, tempBuf
    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine
    jmp near copy_and_swap

swap_with_line1:
    lea di, tempBuf
    lea si, buf
    mov cx, 128
    rep movsb
    call ReadLine
    call WriteLine
    lea si, tempBuf
    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine
    jmp near copy_and_swap


You should include the ReadLine and WriteLine procedures. We can't possibly know how they need to be used correctly!


mov ax, currentLine
cmp ax, line1
je swap_with_line2
cmp ax, line2
je swap_with_line1


Once you read line1 you will go and swap it with line2 that you read locally in the swap_with_line2 routine. Therefore the cmp ax, line2 je swap_with_line1 need not exist, nor the swap_with_line1 routine.
But that local read of line 2 must be accounted for through an extra increment of currentLine.

rep movsb
call ReadLine
call WriteLine


Don't you need a lea si, buf right before this call WriteLine, similar to lea si, tempBuf call WriteLine ?

If you program ReadLine so that it accepts an address to load the line to, then the simple solution will not need to copy at all:
copy_and_swap:
    lea  si, buf
    call ReadLine
    jc   eof
    mov  ax, currentLine
    cmp  ax, line1
    je   swap_with_line2

    ...

; line1 is in buf
swap_with_line2:
    lea  si, tempBuf
    call ReadLine
    lea  si, tempBuf
    call WriteLine
    inc  currentLine
    lea  si, Buf
    call WriteLine
    inc  currentLine
    jmp near copy_and_swap

